# How can one predict asteroid orbit, with the use of vector calculus?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, asteroids

If you are given, (or found) the position and velocity vectors of an asteroid how can one use this to predict its orbit?

Comment: Classical mechanics

Comment: Taking into account only the gravity of the Sun? Or also all the planets? How about the other asteroids, comets, etc.?

Comment: @Ghoster I would like clarification on both just the sun and other planets. Thank you.

Comment: In the case of just the Sun, you have two choices: 1. Numerically integrate the equation of motion with your two vectors as the initial conditions. 2. Use its known general analytic solution of an elliptical (or possibly parabolic or hyperbolic) orbit, fitting it to your initial conditions. In the case of including the planets, you only have option 1 because there is no analytic solution.

Comment: So what you should learn about is how to numerically integrate a second-order differential equation. This is conceptually easy — the force tells you the acceleration which tells you the change in velocity over a short time interval, and the velocity tells you the change in the position — but numerically tricky. Naïve integration schemes will have poor accuracy, won’t conserve energy, etc.

Comment: If you don’t understand what “equation of motion” means, it means $m\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}=\vec F_\text{grav}$.

Comment: @Ghoster THANK YOU SO MUCHHH FOR A DETAILED EXPLINATION!

Comment: This is probably too broad for Stack Exchange. We can't explain celestial mechanics in the space of an answer, it takes a whole book (or several), eg https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/celestial/Celestialhtml/Celestialhtml.html & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Meeus

Comment: However, we can answer specific questions about celestial mechanics, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676872/123208 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/677727/123208 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48477/16685

Comment: It's fun to calculate orbits, but it's a lot of work to do it properly. Of course, if you just want to know the orbit of a Solar System body, it's easier to just ask NASA. ;)  https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/

Comment: @PM2Ring OKAY THANKS! ill check out the sites you listed!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_determination for an overview.